# Search Form in Rails for specific url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the simple_hashtag gem (https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag)

My routes for these hashtags look like this:

```
get 'hashtags/:hashtag', to: 'hashtags#show',      as: :hashtag
```

So to show the hashtag `design` the url would be `/hashtags/design`.

I'd like to create a search form on this page so users can search for a hashtag and it redirect to this url with the appropriate hashtags.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The gem includes the `ActiveRecord::Base` model `SimpleHashtag` which can be used to search hashtags. Your form could look like this:

```
<%= form_for :search, :url => your_result_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :q %><br />
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Of cause you have to replace `your_result_path` with a path helper that actually exists. Then in the controller action which receives the data you can use this code to provice the search results:

```
@results = SimpleHashtag.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search][:q]}%")
```

Then in the view you can loop through the results which are accessable as `@results`.

```
<ul>
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <li><%= link_to result.name, result %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @davidb. This is giving me the error `undefined method "[]" for nil:NilClass` and points to the variable in the controller

Comment: Please post the whole call from your log when you try this including the params.